# Why My web site time out while running JMeter load Test

Tags: timeout, jmeter, load-testing

I'm new to JMeter and. I followed [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jmeter/jmeter_web_test_plan.htm) tutorial to learn JMeter.

I tried to do a load tested under following conditions.

```
 Number of Threads (Users) - 1000

 Ramp-Up Period (in seconds) - 10

 Loop Count - 5
```

While I'm running the test, I tried to load my website (after clear cache)But, it takes more than usual time to load the page. This issue doesn't occur when the browser has cached data.

Can someone please tell me why this is happening? Is it because of when 1000 users load my site, it may crash or something?

Any kind of explanation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While running your JMeter test if you try to load your website (after clear cache), it will always take more time to load than usual.It's because you have cleared the cache and now the browser needs to **render the page resources again** to load your desired page.After loading is complete and if you try to load the page again without clearing cache, it will take less time to load the page this time.Browser does not fetch page resources every time, rather the browser saves it in its cache.So next time when you try to open or load that page, the browser could use those cache to open that page for you in the shortest period of time. So for the first time when a browser load a page it takes more time than loading that specific page later(**without clearing cache**).

Another point is , as your Jmeter test was running while you tried to load your website, it will take a longer time to load your website.Because your application was already handling some requests send by JMeter.So handling extra load will impact on your website page response time.

> **Ramp up time 10sec for 1000 users!!!**

It is not the best practice. You have to give enough time to warm up those **1000 users**. **10 sec** is too small to be the **ramp up time** for **1000 users**.So during the JMeter test period, it is obvious that your browser will take an unexpected time to load your webpage(using Browser) or end up notifying **"Connection Timeout"**.It necessarily doesn't mean that your application is crashed. It's simply because of unrealistic test script design in JMeter.

Answer (score 1):

Could you elaborate on the type of webserver software you are using e.g?
- **Apache HTTPD 2.4** / Nginx / Apache Tomcat / IIS

And the underlying operating system?
- **Windows (Server?)** / Mac OS X / Linux

If your webserver machine is not limited by the maximum performance of your CPU, Disk etc. (check the Task Manager) your performance might be limited by the configuration of Apache.

Could you please check the Apache HTTPD log files for relevant warnings?

Depending on your configuration (httpd.conf + any files "Include"d from there) you may be using the mpm_winnt worker, that has a configurable number of worker threads which by default is 64 according to:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#threadsperchild

Once these are all busy new requests from any client (your browser, your loadtest, etc.) will have to wait for their turn.

Try and see what happens if you increase the number of threads!

Comment: Apache and Windows